# Negative Continued Fraction of a Rational

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

The $n^{\text{th}}$ *negative continued fraction convergent* $x_n$ of a positive real $x$ is computed by the nested function
\begin{align}
x_n = k_1 - \frac{1}{k_2 - \frac{1}{k_3 - \dots - \tfrac{1}{k_n}}},
\end{align}
where $k_1, \dots, k_n$ are positive integers for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. To compute the first $n$ negative continued fraction coefficients, namely, $\{k_1, \dots, k_n \}$, of an arbitrary irrational $x$, I use the following example Mathematica code:

```
 x = Sqrt[2];
 n = 15;
 Map[#[[1, 1]] &, Rest[NestList[1/(Ceiling[#] - #) &, x, n]]].
```

which outputs $\{ 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4 \}$. However, this code is not suitable if $x$ is a rational, since the recurrence diverges when $\#$ is an integer. How might I modify the above code to allow for rational $x$ and output the finite list of coefficients of its complete negative continued fraction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One can implement a general formula:

$$
x = a_1 + \cfrac{b}{a_2
          + \cfrac{b}{a_3
          + \cfrac{b}{\ddots + \cfrac{b}{a_n} } } }
$$

```
continuedFraction[x_, n_, b_: 1] := 
  Sign[b] Reap[NestWhile[b/# - Sow@Floor[b/#] &, Abs[b]/x, # != 0 &, 1, n]][[2, 1]];
```

If `b = 1` it is the regular continued fraction

```
ContinuedFraction[Sqrt[2], 10]
continuedFraction[Sqrt[2], 10]
```

> {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}
>
> {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}

If `b = -1` it is the negative continued fraction

```
continuedFraction[Sqrt[2], 10, -1]
```

> {2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2}

It also works for rationals (it can has less then `n` elements)

```
continuedFraction[4/15, 10, -1]
```

> {1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2}

```
1 - 1/(2 - 1/(2 - 1/(3 - 1/(2 - 1/2))))
```

> 4/15